# How to obtain raw (unconverted) texture data in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, serialization, textures

I need to serialise an arbitrary OpenGL texture object to be able to restore it later with the *exact* same state and data.

I'm looking for a way to get the texture image data. Here's what I've found so far:

- There's `glGetTexImage`.

  It allows to gets the texture image, but it requires a specified format/type pair (like  (`GL_RGB`, `GL_HALF_FLOAT`) to which it performs a conversion.

  The allowed formats and types don't map 1:1 to image formats though, and won't allow to get more obscure formats like `GL_R3_G3_B2` without additional conversion.

  Also correctly determining the C type for base internal formats (like `GL_RGB` with no size) involves some non-trivial labour.
- There's `ARB_internalformat_query2` that allows to ask for `GL_GET_TEXTURE_IMAGE_FORMAT` and `GL_GET_TEXTURE_IMAGE_TYPE` which represent the best choices for `glGetTexImage` for a given texture.

  Nice, but suffers from the same limitations as `glGetTexImage` and isn't widely available.
- There's the wonderful `glGetCompressedTexImage` that elegantly returns the compressed texture's data as-is, but it neither works for non-compressed images nor has a counterpart that would.

None of these allows to get or set raw data for non-compressed textures. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is, to find matches of format and type the yield the right data layout.

> The allowed formats and types don't map 1:1 to image formats though, and won't allow to get more obscure formats like GL_R3_G3_B2 without additional conversion.

That would be GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2

> Also correctly determining the C type for base internal formats (like GL_RGB with no size) involves some non-trivial labour.

Yes it does. *puts on sunglasses* Deal with it! ;)

As for the internal format. I hereby [refer you to](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetTexLevelParameter)

```
glGetTexLevelParameter(GL_TEXTURE_…, …, GL_TEXTURE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,…);
glGetTexLevelParameter(GL_TEXTURE_…, …, GL_TEXTURE_{RED,GREEN,BLUE,ALPHA,DEPTH}_TYPE, …);
glGetTexLevelParameter(GL_TEXTURE_…, …, GL_TEXTURE_{RED,GREEN,BLUE,ALPHA,DEPTH}_SIZE, …);
```

Comment: Danke schön! Now I know what I'm dealing with. I've been [putting some effort to put *this thing* together](https://gist.github.com/Kos/4739337) and I'm, er, looking forward to testing it. And I couldn't find perfect matches for some formats like RGB10 or RGBA2. I wish I had `ARB_internalformat_query2` to verify all that easily...